# Why are new cronjobs ignored unless crond is restarted in SLES?

Tags: cron, sles

I added a new cronjob with a user (SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server 9.4):

```
# su - XXX
$ crontab -e
```

and this is what I added:

```
* * * * * echo `date` >> /home/XXX/a.txt
```

but the a.txt isn't created... it will be ONLY created when root restarts the crond...

**Q:** Why?

UPDATE:

```
machine:~ # chage -l XXX
Minimum:    1
Maximum:    99999
Warning:    7
Inactive:   -1
Last Change:        Apr 11, 2011
Password Expires:   Never
Password Inactive:  Never
Account Expires:    Never
machine:~ #
```

so the user or it's password doesn't expired.

UPDATE: 
cron version:

```
cron-3.0.1-920.18
```

and I tried to add a new crontab to the root user.. it's the same :D the new root cronjobs aren't running too.. :D **it looks like "crontab -e" doesn't reloads CROND or something...**

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't run the _second_ time it is scheduled? See the `***` note here: http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3842311

Comment: Several minutes past since I created a new cronjob what should output a.txt in every minute.

Comment: `echo $(date) >>`? Why not just `date >>`?

Comment: For me it works on SLES9 SP4, although it takes one additional minute for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @peterph: you are right:D date > a.txt should also work:D thanks..

Comment: Can you attach `strace` to the `cron` process and check whether it is checking the files every minute for modification (my expectation is you should see some `stat()` calls). You can also try sending SIGHUP to the process - daemons often reload their configurations on this signal.

Comment: umm, I forgot to update this Q, I solved the problem meantime... see answer:D

Comment: Hm, I thought you'd attach strace to the running cron daemon...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
strace crontab -e
```

solved it... dunno how.. but it works now.. but all I wanted to do is to check the crontabs lowlevel "operations"..

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Thats the joke. Nothing. This problem was for several days, all I did was to try strace, and I noticed that the files got created.. :D

Comment: indeed, this seems to be a joke, as attaching `strace` to a random process cannot possible fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code and it worked fine on Red Hat Fedora 14.

```
* * * * * echo `date` >> /home/saml/a.txt
```

Output of file:

```
$ tail -f a.txt 
Fri Oct 4 14:38:01 EDT 2013
Fri Oct 4 14:39:01 EDT 2013
Fri Oct 4 14:40:01 EDT 2013
```

#### Things to try

1. Can you please confirm that the `crond` service is running:

   ```
   $ sudo service --status-all |& grep crond
   crond (pid  1673) is running...
   ```
2. Confirm setup of cron's spool dir.

   ```
   $ rpm -qf $(type -P /usr/sbin/crond)
   cronie-1.4.8-2.fc14.x86_64

   $ rpm -ql cronie | grep '/var'
   /var/spool/cron
   ```

   List whatever your directory happens to be, we're checking for existence and permissions here:

   ```
   $ sudo ls -ld /var/spool/cron/
   drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Oct  4 14:37 /var/spool/cron/

   $ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
   total 4
   -rw------- 1 root root  0 Sep 16 23:47 root
   -rw------- 1 saml root 42 Oct  4 14:37 saml
   ```
3. SELinux

   Do cronjob's have access via SELinux to write to your /home/XXX dir.?

   A quick test would be to temporarily disable SELinux enforcement to see if it resolves your issue.

   ```
   $ getenforce
   Disabled
   ```

   If it's enabled, disable it:

   ```
   $ sudo setenforce 0
   ```

Comment: it didn't worked.

Comment: @gaskopeter - please update your Q with the results of what I suggested. As it stands we need more information to triage your issue further.